# how can I display the folder path in the textbox

Tags: powershell

```
$handler_installationfolderlocalinstall_Click = {
  $SelectFolder.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
  Write-Host "You selected $SelectFolder $($SelectFolder.SelectedPath)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
  $textboxinstallfolderlocal.Text = $SelectFolder.FileName
}
```

I want to display the folder name in a textbox with "FileName" but it doesn't work.
Which extension is for folder? or How can I display it?

[image: picture]

The path of the folder should be in the textbox as in the lower textbox with the file, but because it is a folder .FileName does not work.

[image: picture2]

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Please be more descriptive than "it doesn't work" - do you get an unexpected value showing up in the textbox? No value? Does it throw an error? If so, what does the error message say?

Comment: No error appears but the folder path is not displayed. I have updated the question again with a new image.

Comment: There's not enough information here to be able to tell. Please post an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (or post the full script)

Comment: this is the code for the files "$handler_softwarelocalinstallation_Click= 
{
$OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$textboxsoftwarelocal.Text = $OpenFileDialog1.FileName

}" and it worked to display the path for the file but with the .FileName command i can't Display the Folder location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the forum.  If your dialog box is returning a directory, 'filename' is not a property of a directoryinfo object.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-5.0

If you want to see what values are available, open a new shell (for testing) and run this against a directory:

```
## This will show you the return type of the object so you can figure this out on your own in the future
(Get-Item SomeDirectory).GetType()

## Then after that, run this:
Get-Item SomeDirectory | Get-Member
```

...which will show you all of the 'Properties' and 'Methods' (together known as 'Members') available on the directory object -- or any other object for that matter.

I suspect, for a directory, you'll want to use one of these properties:  Name, FullName, or BaseName.

GL!